# Сообщение при отключении бота telegram aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, бот

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы после отключения бота с машины, он выдавал сообщение в чат, например: "Бот офлайн". Если можно, то как это реализовать?

Comment: **после** отключения никакая программа не сможет выполнить никаких действий.

Answer (score 1):

```
# импортируем модуль telebot для работы с Telegram API
import telebot
# импортируем модуль atexit для регистрации функции завершения программы
import atexit

# создаем объект бота, указывая токен авторизации
bot = telebot.TeleBot("YOUR_TOKEN_HERE")

# определяем идентификатор чата, куда будут отправляться сообщения от бота
chat_id = "YOUR_CHAT_ID_HERE"

# определяем функцию-обработчик команды /start, которая будет вызываться при ее получении
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    # отправляем ответное сообщение, когда бот получает команду /start
    bot.reply_to(message, "Hello! I'm your bot.")

# регистрируем функцию goodbye() в качестве функции завершения программы
@atexit.register
def goodbye():
    # отправляем сообщение о том, что бот выключен в чат с указанным идентификатором
    bot.send_message(chat_id, "Bot offline")

# запускаем бота в бесконечном цикле, получая новые сообщения и вызывая соответствующие функции-обработчики
bot.polling()
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
executor.start_polling(dp, on_shutdown=some_function)
```

Вроде так, ещё можно назначить функцию которая отвечает за момент, когда бот включается.